# Extremes points of the set of certain increasing convex functions

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, function-spaces

I am wondering if anyone could help me figure out the following problem.

Let $F$ denote the set of all functions $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ such that $f$ is weakly convex, increasing, continuous (at end points), $f(0) =0$, $f(1) =1$, and falls between $\overline{f}$ and $\underline{f}$ such that
$\overline{f}(x) = x$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, $\underline{f}(x) = 0$ for $x \le 1/2$, and $\underline{f}(x) = 2x-1$ for $x \ge 1/2$.

We can regard $F$ as a convex set in the set of all continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$.

My question is: What would be extreme points of $F$? In particular, can we say something like any extreme point, as a function of $x$, has less than a certain number of kinks?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I can see that piecewise linear functions that equal $0$ below some $\underline{x}$ and equal $2x-1$ above some $\overline{x}$ would be extreme points. However, I haven't figured out how to construct convex combinations of these functions so that they converge to other (non-extreme) functions.